# How to locate an element within bad html python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, data-mining, data-extraction

I want to scrape the Athletic Director's information from this page. but the issue is that there is a strong tag that refers to the name and email of every person on the page. I only want an XPath that specifically extracts the exact name and email of the Athletic Director. Here is the link to the website for a better understanding of the code. "https://fhsaa.com/sports/2020/1/28/member_directory.aspx"

```html
<div id="school_detail"><div class="row" align="center"><div class="bottom-spacing col-md-4"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-md" onclick="showAthleticFaculty(10)">Athletic Faculty</button></div><div class="bottom-spacing col-md-4"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-md" onclick="showCoachesAndSports(10)">Coaches &amp; Sports</button></div><div class="bottom-spacing col-md-4"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-md" onclick="showSchoolDetail(10)">School Information</button></div></div><br><h5 align="center"><u><strong>American (Hialeah) - Athletic Faculty</strong></u></h5><div><h6 class="athletic-faculty-header">Volunteer</h6></div><strong>N/A</strong><br><br><div><h6 class="athletic-faculty-header">Principal/Head Master</h6></div><strong>Name:</strong>  Stephen <br><strong>Email:</strong> <a href="mailto:StephenPapp@dadeschools.net">StephenPapp@dadeschools.net</a><br><br><div><h6 class="athletic-faculty-header">Athletic Director</h6></div><strong>Name:</strong>  Marcus Gabriel<br><strong>Email:</strong> <a href="mailto:mgabriel@dadeschools.net">mgabriel@dadeschools.net</a><br><br><div><h6 class="athletic-faculty-header">Assistant/Co AD</h6></div><strong>Name:</strong>  Ginette Torres<br><strong>Email:</strong> <a href="mailto:gtcastro@dadeschools.net">gtcastro@dadeschools.net</a><br><br><div><h6 class="athletic-faculty-header">Assistant/Vice Principal</h6></div><strong>Name:</strong>  Alex Gonzalez<br><strong>Email:</strong> <a href="mailto:agonza12@dadeschools.net">agonza12@dadeschools.net</a><br><br><div><h6 class="athletic-faculty-header">Administrative Assistant/Athletics</h6></div><strong>Name:</strong>  Shanell <br><strong>Email:</strong> <a href="mailto:slyoung005@gmail.com">slyoung005@gmail.com</a><br><br><div><h6 class="athletic-faculty-header">Financial/Bookkeeper Contact</h6></div><strong>Name:</strong>  Christopher Keighley<br><strong>Email:</strong> <a href="mailto:217441@dadeschools.net">217441@dadeschools.net</a><br><br><div><h6 class="athletic-faculty-header">Athletic Trainer</h6></div><strong>Name:</strong>  Gorin Aaron<br><strong>Email:</strong> <a href="mailto:333956@dadeschools.net">333956@dadeschools.net</a><br><br><div><h6 class="athletic-faculty-header">Medical - First Responder</h6></div><strong>N/A</strong><br><br></div>
```

Comment: How do I reach there?

Comment: cruisepandey Dear I can't get it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to get the email id, use this :-

```
//h6[text()='Athletic Director']/../following-sibling::strong[text()='Email:']/following-sibling::a
```

**Update :**

```
print(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//h6[text()='Athletic Director']/../following-sibling::strong[text()='Email:']/following-sibling::a").text)
```

**Update 1 :**

```
elem = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//h6[text()='Athletic Director']/../following-sibling::strong[text()='Name:']")
name = driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].nextSibling.textContent;", elem)
print(name)
```

Comment: But It is extracting all the 19 tags on the page.

Comment: //h6[text()='Athletic Director']/../following-sibling::strong

Comment: print(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//h6[text()='Athletic Director']/../following-sibling::strong[text()='Email:']/following-sibling::a").text)

Comment: Please check … It returns email of every person ..//h6[text()='Athletic Director']/../following-sibling::strong[text()='Email:']/following-sibling::a

Comment: yes try to print that, you should get the email `mgabriel@dadeschools.net`

Comment: I think you are using find_elements

Comment: But in strong its only text "Name:" the director's name is not in the strong tag.

Comment: actually those are called text nodes, `return arguments[0].nextSibling` see this line, we are looking for next sibling of the strong, do try it out first and let me know how it goes

Comment: I am sorry for asking too much but I am new and can't get where to put the return 'arguments[0].nextSibling'